# navigation links in joomla articles

Tags: hyperlink, joomla, navigation, joomla-article

i have some problem that in articles its not showing the navigation links even i have set the perameters yes and default plugin is set.
so plz help me out for the same
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What template are you using? Are you sure that the template supports the article navigation? Switch the default template to Beez or Milky Way and see if it works there. If it does, you need to modify your template.

Comment: Hmm. I did some digging and in this case the template does not actually matter as the event that pagenavigation.php is listening for is onBeforeDisplayContent so it is independent of the template. The 2 places that control the page nav are the global parameters (Content->Article Manager->Parameters->Show Navigation) and in the menu item (Menus->Your Menu Item->Parameters (Component)->Show Navigation).